# Google Cloud Speech API iOS returns 401 UNAUTHENTICATED with Firebase Storage File

Tags: ios, firebase-storage, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to transcribe long files(>1min) using Google Cloud Speech Api from my iOS app.
For that purpose, I do following:

1) As written in docs, I authenticate user anonymously to firebase

```
[[FIRAuth auth]
 signInAnonymouslyWithCompletion:^(FIRUser *_Nullable user, NSError *_Nullable error) {
     // ...
     if (!error){
         self.user = user;

         [self.user getTokenWithCompletion:^(NSString * _Nullable token, NSError * _Nullable error) {
             if (!error) {
                 self.token = token;
                 [self uploadFile];
             }
         }];

     }
 }];
```

2) Then I upload my file to Firebase Storage and get the URI

```
- (void)uploadFile
{

    FIRStorage * storage = [FIRStorage storage];
    FIRStorageReference *storageRef = [storage reference];
    FIRStorageReference *sonetRef = [storageRef child:@"transcribeTest/sonet130.mp3"];

    NSData *sonet = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sonet130" ofType:@"mp3"]];

    FIRStorageUploadTask *uploadTask  = [sonetRef putData:sonet metadata:nil completion:^(FIRStorageMetadata * _Nullable metadata, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (error != nil) {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        } else {
            // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
            NSURL *downloadURL = metadata.downloadURL;

            NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"gs://%@/%@",metadata.bucket,metadata.path];

            NSURL * gsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];//@"gs://%@",downloadURL.path]];

            [self trnscribeFileAtURL:gsURL];
        }

    }];
    [uploadTask resume];
}
```

3) The next step should be sending Asyncrecognize request to Google Cloud Speech API. But I get 401 Error ''.

```
-(void)trnscribeFileAtURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    NSString *service = @"https:/speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:asyncrecognize";
    service = [service stringByAppendingString:@"?key="];
    service = [service stringByAppendingString:API_KEY];

    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self soundFilePath]];
    NSDictionary *configRequest = @{@"encoding":@"LINEAR16",
                                    @"sampleRate":@(SAMPLE_RATE),
                                    @"languageCode":@"en-UK",
                                    @"maxAlternatives":@30};
    NSDictionary *audioRequest = @{@"uri":url.absoluteString};
    NSDictionary *requestDictionary = @{@"config":configRequest,
                                        @"audio":audioRequest};
    NSError *error;
    NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestDictionary
                                                          options:0
                                                            error:&error];

    NSString *path = service;
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    // if your API key has a bundle ID restriction, specify the bundle ID like this:
    [request addValue:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier"];
    NSString *contentType = @"application/json";
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",self.token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSURLSessionTask *task =
    [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
     dataTaskWithRequest:request
     completionHandler:
     ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                        ^{
                            NSString *stringResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                            _textView.text = stringResult;
                            NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", stringResult);
                        });
     }];
    [task resume];

}
```

The response JSON:

```
2017-02-28 19:58:05.837337 Speech[8057:2054726] RESULT: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Looks like problem lies on this line of code:

```
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",self.token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

I am trying to pass token that I get from Firebase Anonymous auth, but it does not suit. I've searched the obtain I cant find how to obtain right credentials for anonymous user. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't use a Firebase Auth token to access Google APIs like Speech or Vision directly from the client. As the error message says, those APIs expect one of:

- Google OAuth 2.0 (either user initiated or via a service account)
- Login cookie

See more info in [the Speech docs on authentication](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/common/auth).

The easiest way to do this is probably using something like [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) and listen for a file upload, then process the audio, and write it back to the database.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear and giving alternative way.